# css styles not being applied?

Tags: html, css, styles

i wanted to design header but my styles is not working my styles are not being applied to this class, this is my code.

```css
.nav-link {
color: inherit;
font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
font-size: var(--fs-h1);
}


.logo{
 max-width: 100px;
}

header{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 1em;
}

.nav{
position: fixed;
background: var(--clr-dark);
color: var(--clr-light);
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 100;

transform: translateX(0%);
transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .5, 1);
}

.nav-list{
 list-style: none;
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

.nav-link {
 color: inherit;
 font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
 font-size: var(--fs-h1);
 }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="image/logo-naam.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="hamburger"></span>
  </button>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#home"></a>Home</li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#services"></a>My services</li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"></a>About me</li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#work"></a>My work</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

It does apply the padding of the H1 but not the style??? Is it maybe overwritten by something else? I am  not sure how it's happening any kind of help will be appreciateble

Comment: Where are you referencing your stylesheet?

Comment: it's connected i'm sure of that.

Comment: have you check in your browser console if the css is connected?

Comment: all my other styles apply.

Comment: the value for the variable isn't applied?

Answer (score -1):

```css
:root {
  --clr-dark: #000;
  --clr-light: #ddd;
  --fw-bold: bold;
  --fs-h1: 40px;
}
/* header */

.logo{
 max-width: 100px;
}

header{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 1em;
}

.nav{
position: fixed;
background: var(--clr-dark);
color: var(--clr-light);
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 100;

transform: translateX(0%);
transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .5, 1);
}

.nav-list{
 list-style: none;
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

.nav-link {
 color: inherit;
 font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
 font-size: var(--fs-h1);
 }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="image/logo-naam.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="hamburger"></span>
  </button>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#home"></a>Home</li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#services"></a>My services</li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about"></a>About me</li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#work"></a>My work</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

You need to declare root var first then you can use variable css. Otherwise it'll not work.

Comment: i have declared them but it's over 300 lines of code i didn't want to put everything in here.